# How to add CA cert to OpenBSD (6.4)

Tags: openbsd

I'm trying to add a CA certificate to OpenBSD.

- I have copied the `conmpany.crt` to `/etc/ssl/private`
- I have created the `.0` file from the certificate (using `openssl x509 -hash -noout -in company.crt`)
- I can run `openssl verify -CApath /etc/ssl/private/ company.crt` just fine; result: `company.crt: OK`

However, when I try: `curl -vi https://company.example/` I get:

```
*   Trying 192.168.XXX.XXX...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to company.example (192.168.XXX.XXX) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

From what I gather from the message curl looks at/in `/etc/ssl/cert.pem`. I could add the `.crt` to that file but a) I don't know what the correct way is and b) won't it get removed whenever I update all Root Certificates? I was hoping I could keep our own certificate(s) in a separate location. I haven't been able to find much on google so far other than that a `.0` file is, apparently, required. But then on how to actually *use* the certificate is nowhere to be found.

Oh, also, the provided link in the error message (https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) isn't very helpful.

---

To be clear, this is what I do on Debian machines which works fine:

- Copy the `company.crt` to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/company` (where the `company` directory has `chmod 755` and the `company.crt` has `chmod 644`)
- Run `update-ca-certificates`
- ...
- Profit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append the cert to the end of `/etc/ssl/cert.pem`:

```
# cat mycert.pem >> /etc/ssl/cert.pem
```

which will stick across updates (see `man sysmerge`).

Note that sometimes the file is ignored (e.g. some browsers only trust their own CA repository).

Comment: Great! Thanks for confirming and pointing me in the right direction!